# Oracle AUTO COMMIT

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Could some body help me on auto commit of below statements. How do you I use Commit statement in Oracle to avoid the auto commit confirmation dialogue boxes?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE manual_list_backup; 

INSERT INTO manual_list_backup 
SELECT * 
FROM   manual_transactions
```

I am executing the above statement in TOAD Data-point. Every time this statement is run I get the Dialogue box saying that

> You have uncommitted changes on 'My schema Name'. Do you want to commit them?

Unless I say YES to this dialogue box the above statement will not produce any results

Comment: Autocommit is a *client* feature. What client do you use?

Comment: As a general rule, in most (all?) relational DBMS you cannot use transactions for DDL statetements like `TRUNCATE TABLE`. Other than that, the Oracle server will obviously not display dialogues—what program is your question about?

Comment: I am executing the above statement in TOAD data-point. Every time this statement is run  I get the Dialogue box saying that "You have uncommitted changes on 'My schema Name'.Do you want to commit them".Unless i say YES to this dialogue box the above statement will not produce any results.

Comment: @santhosha - in future please *edit your question* to include additional information.  Comments are meant for transitory or tangential remarks.  It should be possible to remove all the comments from a thread without diminishing the useful information in it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I'd put it the other way round: Oracle is one of the few to *not* support transactional DDL.  Postgres, SQL Server, Firebird and DB2 support transactional DDL. In Postgres and SQL Server you *can* rollback a `truncate` (not sure about the others)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ". Every time this statement is run I get the Dialogue box saying that
>   "You have uncommitted changes on 'My schema Name'.Do you want to
>   commit them"."

So what you're really complaining about is *a feature of TOAD*.  Because Oracle will quite simply execute the implicit COMMIT for any DDL statement.  Your problem is that TOAD is interfering with the default Oracle behaviour with its chiding dialogue box.

This nannying tone is one reason why I dislike IDEs so much.  They are often slick and helpful   but sometimes they just need to step out of the way and let us get on with the jobs.

It's been a long time since I used TOAD (too expensive) but there ought to be a way to switch off this dialogue.  Is there a checkbox on the dialogbox itself?  Something like *Always show this message?*  Alternatively, there may be something in the `View | Toad Options` menu, perhaps under `Oracle | Transactions`.  A sophisticated IDE such as TOAD is highly customisable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you suggested there is an option to enable Auto commit on.This has solved my problem now. Once again thanks a lot for all your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can not rollback TRUNCATE statement.

The operation cannot be rolled back and no triggers will be fired. As such, TRUNCATE is faster and doesn't use as much undo space as a DELETE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @santhosha - To achieve what? Do you want to be able to rollback a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement? What prevents you from using `DELETE`?